# Allowing Save Prompt With Combobox Used to Change Records

Tags: vba, ms-access, userform

I have a form with various project numbers. I have navigational buttons on my form such as Previous, Undo, Save, Refresh, Delete, Add Record, Next Record, and Save and Close.

I also have a combo box with a drop-down list. It displays the current project number, and when you select another number from this combo box, the form will jump to that record.

I have code in the form’s Before Update section that prompts a user to save changes before moving to another record.

```vb
If Not (Me.NewRecord) Then
    If MsgBox("Would you like to save changes to this record?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Save Changes to Record?") = vbNo Then
        Me.Undo
    End If
Else
    If MsgBox("Would you like to save changes to this record?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Save this Record?") = vbNo Then
        Me.Undo
    End If
End If
```

It works if you use the navigation buttons.

When you use the combo box to change records, and you say Yes to saving changes, the record will not change and then the program gets confused by a conflict between the new number and the existing number. The script breaks. When you try to change records again, you get the message "Update or CancelUpdate without AddNew or Edit", followed by "The value violates the validation rule for the field or record."

I want to keep the option to save before jumping records, and I like using a combo box to jump records. Is there a way to fix this by modifying the code, or by modifying my form design?

Comment: Since you have the same message and action for both new and existing record, why bother with testing if it is NewRecord? Is combobox UNBOUND?

Comment: Should use `Cancel = True` in form BeforeUpdate when user responds No. Perhaps don't rely on form BeforeUpdate at all for this validation. I cannot recall ever using it. I control record Save/Undo in the buttons.

Comment: You're right that the distinction between New and Existing records may be redundant.  I have tested Cancel = True and can see that it handles the error, but my overall problem isn't solved.

Comment: I want a system that makes the user aware that when they're changing records (either by Previous/Next or by the combobox), they are about to save changes.  My understanding is that a Save button works but if the user can navigate to other records without hitting Save, Access still saved all changes made without making the user aware.

Comment: What would really be nice is to maybe treat the combobox BeforeUpdate save prompt separately from the save prompt given while hitting Previous/Next/Save in the Form BeforeUpdate, so that the Form BeforeUpdate only considers everything BUT the combobox changes, and when the combobox is about to change and the user wants to save changes they've made, stop them from jumping records and stay on the previous record so they can hit the Save button.  I don't know the code necessary to do this, however, and could use some help.

Comment: Form design can prevent navigation to other records except by your custom buttons. Edit question to show the combobox code.

Comment: If there was a way to prevent autosaving in a form except via using the Save button, that would be useful and I'd like to know how.  

As for navigation, I want the user to be able to navigate using Previous, Next, and the combobox.  In fact, most users of this database only navigate by choosing a project number (showing columns for Project Name and Client as reference columns) from the combobox list.  So keeping that combobox functionality is very important.

What do you mean by 'edit question to show the combobox code'?  The combobox doesn't have any save-specific code at present.

Comment: You said the combobox is used to jump to another record so there is code associated with combobox. I didn't suggest it was save-specific. However, it seems to be relevant to issue regardless.

Comment: Oh, that.  It was done using the Form Wizard and is an embedded macro using SearchforRecord using Where Condition == "[Project Number]="&"'"& [Screen].[ActiveControl]&"'"

Comment: I don't use wizards or macros so I used VBA instead of macro for combobox event. I don't get error message. After enter data and then make selection in combobox, I respond Yes to save, record is saved and code navigates to record. I respond No edit is not saved and code does not navigate. I think this is situation you experienced after adding Cancel = True. Apparently, it cancels everything. Only suggestion I can make is to not use form BeforeUpdate event.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips.  I took your advice and also combined it with both a tutorial on how to ONLY save using a save button
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZsQ0lp4m74
combined with a tutorial on how to add a save button and only enabling it when a change has been made
https://www.iaccessworld.com/create-save-button-notification-save-change/
and adding a message box On Dirty to remind the user to save changes using the Save button.  This seems to accomplish what I want and stops the bug from happening while switching records using the combobox.  I'll share my code.

Answer (score 0):

This setup will allow saving ONLY when someone using the Save button (btnSave) or a button I made called Save and Close (btnCloseForm).  Other forms of form navigation will NOT save changes.

I kept my combobox code After Update as the embedded macro created by the form wizard to retrieve the first record with the SearchforRecord function using Where Condition == "[Project Number]="&"'"& [Screen].[ActiveControl]&"'".  I'm sure this part can be re-created easily with VBA code instead.

The VBA code I used in my form to make it work:

```
Option Compare Database
Private Saved As Boolean

Private Sub btnCloseForm_Click()
Saved = True
DoCmd.RunCommand (acCmdSaveRecord)
DoCmd.Close
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click()
If MsgBox("Would you like to save changes to this record?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Save this Record?") = vbYes Then
 Saved = True
 DoCmd.RunCommand (acCmdSaveRecord)
 Me.btnSave.Enabled = False
 Saved = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If Saved = False Then
 Cancel = True
 Me.Undo
 Cancel = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
Me.btnSave.Enabled = False
Saved = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)
Me.btnSave.Enabled = True
MsgBox ("Please remember to save changes using the Save button.")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a second solution for this problem.  I made the combobox for navigation unbound, and just added a second text box to display the project number that was bound.  Using this combination, I kept the BeforeUpdate catch-all prompt to ask the user if they want to save changes.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If MsgBox("Would you like to save changes to this record?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Save Changes to Record?") = vbNo Then
 Me.Undo
 End If
End Sub
```